# Remote SQL Connection Failing due to MS SQL Server running under a domain account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, kubernetes

I'm getting a strange issue with one Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I get the following error if the MS SQL Server runs under a domain account. Just from one Linux client, all other clients work as expected.

> An unhandled exception has occurred: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

If I change the Microsoft SQL Server to run under the server's local NetworkService Account, it works fine on that linux host.

If I change the Linux client to connect to another MS SQL Server running under the same Domain Account, it works.

All other servers are fine. I tried many things, but nothing seemed to work. All I can imagine is that there is something funny on one of the servers that causes it to fail. And another odd thing is there are times when the call works perfectly from that Linux client, then after a minute it stops working again.

I have tried using stopping the encryption on the connection string as well as using the server cert option. Does not work either.

Any ideas as to how I can get past this?

Comment: Which version and build of SQL Server `select @@version`

Comment: The problematic server's details are as follows.
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3) (KB5003279) - 13.0.6300.2 (X64)   Aug  7 2021 01:20:37   Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Is the Linux machine connecting using an AD account (Windows Authentication) or using SQL Authentication? If the former, is it domain joined, and is the SQL Server joined to the same domain?

Comment: Sql authentication. And yes sql server is joined to the domain.